# Range union with Google Guava

Tags: java, range, guava, intervals

I am writing some code that needs to work with numeric ranges. I am using Google Guava library; I need some basic operations, like union and intersection.

Looking at Google Guava Documentation, intersection between ranges can be easily made with range.intersection(range) method, but I can't find any union method; the only viable option seems using RangeSet class, but it will bring even more issues: for example, it's not very intuitive to scroll every range in RangeSet...

Is there any way to merge set using Google Guava or other libraries?

It would be ok even to change library, if there are any better/more intuitive option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`span` will take the union of two ranges that touch each other.

In any other case, you will have to use `RangeSet`, though it's not very clear to me what's so unintuitive about it.

Comment: If I use the RangeSet class, as I tried, intersect and span functions use Range as input, not RangeSet. This would mean that if I want to process two rangesets with intersection or union, I should process every single range in Rangeset of one of them (while the other RangeSet will be used to call the function); I can't find such a method (the one unrolling the rangeSet) in the documentation.

For me, It would have been intuitive to have a Rangeset.intersect(otherRangeset) method, for example.

Comment: To get the union of two `RangeSet`s, call `rangeSet1.addAll(rangeSet2)`.  To intersect two `RangeSet`s, call `rangeSet1.removeAll(rangeSet2.complement())`.  To iterate over a `RangeSet`, call `asSetOfRanges()` to get a `Set` you can iterate over as normal.  In general, it's based on the APIs exposed by classes like Map and Set, e.g. that `Map` requires you get the `entrySet` to iterate over it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I know that APIs were designed with a precise purpose, in this case the similarity to Map/Set classes, but I was looking for a more "specific purpose" approach. However, I will try to rewrite my code based on the suggestion you gave me.